# Did Keys know that the code was used in Free City?

Tags: free-guy

I just watched Free Guy in theaters, and I was very confused about an aspect of the plot. In the beginning of the movie, Keys didn't think Antwan used the code, but by the end

> Keys knows where the code is so much he hid a secret bridge to get to it as a cheat

So did Keys know about the code use or not?
`

Answer (score 10):

No, Keys didn't know about the code.

Only after Millie discovered where the original code was, she was able to tell Keys.

Keys then built the bridge, in real-time, he didn't reveal a bridge he'd already built.

Comment: I did wonder why he had to repurpose existing buildings to make it rather than just creating it out of nothing, but that's a separate gripe :)

Comment: It seems to be within the rules of the software, materials may be repurposed but not created from scratch when in god mode. Also you can't discount that it looks [cooler (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool#:~:text=Also%20known%20in%20some%20circles,fans%20over%20implausibility%20in%20fiction.)